# Hyperledger Fabric Composer: Unhandled error for request POST /api/Trader: Error: Authorization Required

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I get the following error when trying to create a new trader model:

Unhandled error for request POST /api/Trader: Error: Authorization Required

I'm following the following tutorial: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/queries

It never said anything about authentication and the answers posted online did not yet solve my problems, I saw some stuff about Github OAuth but I either did not understand it or it did not manage to solve my problems.